# Can I use multiple version of ArcGIS desktop on same computer with one EDN license?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager, edn

If I have an EDN license, then can I use multiple versions of ArcMap on the same computer?
For example, I want to install ArcMap 10.0 and 10.4 with my EDN license. Now is it possible to install these two versions on the same computer? If not, then can I install 10.0 on computer_1 and 10.4 on computer_2 (another computer).
I have read from here : [http://www.esri.com/legal/pdfs/mla_e204_e300/english#AGOL_Data][1]

and 
  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/what-you-get

but they are not clear to me.

Comment: Questions about legal issues (licensing, etc) should be posed to your lawyer or the party with whom you entered the agreement. Legal advice from others is worth only as much as you paid to receive it. GISGe did a good job of pointing out Esri's documentation on the agreement, but does not, cannot, constitute legal advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an EDN license you can indeed receive different versions of ArcGIS, for test and development purposes.

**Technical aspects:**
No, you can't install them on the same machine. You would need to use a virtual machine to use different versions on the same computer.

See this Esri article for reference: [FAQ: Can I install different versions of different ArcGIS products on the same machine?](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000005101)

Note that you can install ArcGIS Pro on the same computer as Desktop, they are different softwares.

**Legal aspects**: an EDN license is assigned to one developer, so I suppose as long as you're the only one using the licenses, it should be OK to install them on different machines. It would anyway be weird to provide several versions otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @GISGe, for ur quick response. One more question :                          # Can I install 10.4 on multuple computers with one EDN license ?

Comment: Thank you too! No, 1 EDN license = 1 authorization code. Again 1 EDN is meant to be used by 1 developer, so you shouldn't need to install it on multiple machines (with the exception of Server and Data, see point 24 in the license agreement you reference).